# How do I access a JSONObject subfield?

Tags: java, json, google-geocoder

I feel dumb  but I've been looking around for this for a while.  I'm working with the google geocoder API and I need a bit of help with the json responses.  Here is a JSONObject that I have:

```
{
"viewport": {
    "southwest": {
        "lng": -78.9233749802915,
        "lat": 36.00696951970851
    },
    "northeast": {
        "lng": -78.92067701970849,
        "lat": 36.0096674802915
    }
},
"location_type": "ROOFTOP",
"location": {
    "lng": -78.922026,
    "lat": 36.0083185
}
}
```

How do I pull the "location" subfields out into their own variables?  I tried `jsonObjectVariable.getString("location");` and `jsonObjectVariable.getDouble()` etc. but it's not returning correctly.  What do you call a subfield in a json object?  I've read that you can access subfields with the object.subobject syntax but I'm just not getting what I need.

(I'm using json-org as the library)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please post some code. From the looks of it, BruceLowe's answer below should do what you want, maybe the code can help clear the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With the [json.org library for Java](http://www.json.org/java/), you can only get at the individual properties of an object by first getting the parent `JSONObject` instance:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
JSONObject location = object.getJSONObject("location");
double lng = location.getDouble("lng");
double lat = location.getDouble("lat");
```

If you're trying to access properties using "dotted notation", like this:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
double lng = object.getDouble("location.lng");
double lat = object.getDouble("location.lat");
```

then the json.org library isn't what you're looking for: It does not support this kind of access.

---

As a side node, it makes no sense calling `getString("location")` on any part of the JSON given in your question. The value of the only property that is called "location" is another object with two properties called "lng" and "lat".

If you want this "as a String", the closest thing is to call `toString()` on the `JSONObject location` (first code snippet in this answer) which will give you something like `{"lng":-78.922026,"lat":36.0083185}`.

Comment: I just copied the JSON string from your question and pasted it into a local String variable in Eclipse -- if `object.getJSONObject("location");` throws an exception for you, I suspect the JSON might be different than what's in your question.

Comment: I understand your reasoning for wanting to call `object.getString("location")` -- it's just not how the json.org library works/is defined. `getString()` "get[s] the string associated with a key" or throws an JSONException "if there is no string value for the key." -- and there is no string value for the key "location", only an object value.

Comment: It's not different, I just validated it on jsonlint.org straight from a system.out.  I'm going to try to reload my libraries and clean the project, I'm guessing it's probably eclipse and something with my workspace since everyone keeps recommending the same calls as I tried.  Thanks for the assistance though, I appreciate it.

Comment: yeah but if I call getJSONObject("location");  it should still initialize a location JSONObject... but it's just throwing the error JSONObject["location"] not found.  I've done the exact same thing on a different object and it worked fine.  I must be missing something.  Also I want to call locationobject.toString(), not object.getString("location").  I typed it wrong earlier.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you'd need to use jsonObjectVariable.getJSONObject("location") which in turn returns another JSONObject.

You can then invoke getDouble("lng") or  getDouble("lat") on that object.

E.g.

```
double lat = jsonObjectVariable.getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lat");
```

Comment: This does not work, I tried it just like it says in the question ;)  I evaluate into a JSONObject but when I call the getString function on "location" it's not returning the string of "lat" : derpderp etc.  I know there's a way to access the subfield of this object, I'll keep trying.  I've tried a scanner and pulling scan.nextDouble, but I still can't get either just the string of the items under "location" or doubles of the numbers.

Comment: Given the JSON in the question, the `String lat = ...getString("lat")` should probably  be `double lat = ...getDouble("lat")` instead.

Comment: I just said I tried to scan out a double and I'm trying to pull "location" anyway which should format out as a string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer bruce same as what I was thinking.  Upvoted.

Comment: Thanks guys, i didn't notice it was a really a double (due to the unquoted value) - I've changed the answer from getString to getDouble so future readers will get the correct value

Answer (score 0):

You should create Class Location to pull the "location" subfields.

```
public class Location {
    private double lat;
    private double lng;

@JsonCreator
    public Location(@JsonProperty("lat") double lat, @JsonProperty("lng") double lng {
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lngenter code here = lng;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can extend the JSONObject class and override the `public Object get(String key) throws JSONException` with the following:

```
public Object get(String key) throws JSONException {
    if (key == null) {
        throw new JSONException("Null key.");
    }

    Object object = this.opt(key);
    if (object == null) {
        if(key.contains(".")){
            object = this.getWithDotNotation(key);
        }
        else
            throw new JSONException("JSONObject[" + quote(key) + "] not found.");
    }
    return object;
}


private Object getWithDotNotation(String key) throws JSONException {
    if(key.contains(".")){
        int indexOfDot = key.indexOf(".");
        String subKey = key.substring(0, indexOfDot);
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)this.get(subKey);
        if(jsonObject == null){
            throw new JSONException(subKey + " is null");
        }
        try{
            return jsonObject.getWithDotNotation(key.substring(indexOfDot + 1));                
        }catch(JSONException e){
            throw new JSONException(subKey + "." + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    else
        return this.get(key);
}
```

Please feel free to better handle the exceptions.. im sure it's not handled correctly.
Thanks